# What error checking should I do within this function?

Tags: c

I'm a C-programmer in progress just starting to feel that I get some things right. Being used to much higher level languages (like C# and Python), I really miss my exceptions.

The following is a function I wrote and am currently using to peek into streams X number of chars.

What error checking could be done within this function to make sure it doesn't brake a program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "speek.h"

void speek(char *peek, size_t len, FILE *stream) {

   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      peek[i] = fgetc(stream);
      if (feof(stream) || i >= len - 1) {
         // Null terminate the string if stream is EOF or requested number
         // of characters has already been fetched.
         peek[i] = '\0';
         break;
      }   
   }   

   for (i = strlen(peek); i >= 0; i--) {
      ungetc(peek[i], stream);
   }   
}
```

Comment: This is *the* difficult part of C: you have to decide in advance how you are going to check and report errors, and you have neither exceptions, nor stack unwinding. For I/O failures which you can't recover from, I suggest plainly stopping the program with an error message. For the question per se, every I/O function can fail at any moment (eg. imagine the file is on a USB key and you are removing it while your program is running), so you should check that *every* function executed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always check the FILE* as I read characters.

I think it is a stylistic thing, but I would not put something which I normally intend to happen within the loop.

Finally, a succesfully read string should always be terminated by a '\0'. I am often torn about what to do when there was an error. If I know what the function is for, I could normally choose.

So, using your style of file checking:

```
void speek(char *peek, size_t len, FILE *stream) {

   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < len-1 && !feof(stream); i++) {
      peek[i] = fgetc(stream);
   }   

   peek[i] = '\0';

   for (i = strlen(peek)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (ungetc(peek[i], stream) != peek[i]) {
         break;  // I'd return an error, but function is void
      }
   }   
}
```

If this is more than a quick experiment, or I were writing this for others, I might use assert to check parameters (yes, I know, I still do (c=getc(...)), I'm old)

```
#include <assert.h>

int speek(char *peek, size_t len, FILE *stream) {
   assert(peek != NULL);
   assert(len > 0);    /* Could 0 be okay? */
   assert(stream != NULL && !ferror(stream));

   int i;
   int c;
   for (i = 0; i < len-1 && (c=getc(stream)) != EOF; i++) {
      peek[i] = c;
   }   

   peek[i] = '\0';

   if (ferror(stream)) return -1;

   for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (ungetc(peek[j], stream) != peek[j]) {
         return -1;
      }
   }  
   return i;   /* I like to return something useful */ 
}
```

Edit: I tried to mirror the original but it isn't the way I'd do it, so I finally gave up, and wrote what I'd normally aim to write.

Edit2: ... But I made a mistake. The correct approach is to check there is room for the character **before** reading it. Doh!

Simple test program:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char line0[100];
    int n0 = speek(line0, 4, stdin);

    fprintf(stderr, "%d '%s'\n", n0, line0);

    char line1[100];
    int n1 = speek(line1, 8, stdin);

    fprintf(stderr, "%d '%s'\n", n1, line1);

    return 0;
}
```

Given a file containing only `abcefghij` gives

```
3 'abc' 
7 'abcdefg'
```

Comment: Assert is perfectly fine here, since failed assertion indcates a bug in the program.

Comment: @Alexandre C - Yes. I think, especially when people are learning C, assert is a useful habit; 'assert bugs to death'. It gives the file name and line number of the error which speeds up debugging. It may be the callers fault that those assertions fail, but, when learning, it is 'all my own code', it is still an error, which can be very frustrating to find.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, although something is missing here. Your function, and probably my original one too, is pulling one char too many without pushing it back. I've solved it, but I'm afraid its not as elegant anymore. How would you've done it?

Comment: @frklft - I'm not sure what you mean by "function ... is pulling one char too many without pushing it back". I aimed for `i` == the number of actual characters read (and hence index of the terminating `'\0'`) and `i <= len-1`. Then `j=i-1`, the index of the last character read, and put back all down to, and including, index 0. What have I missed?

Comment: If the stream is: `abcdefghij`, and you invoke `speek(string, 4, stream)`, then string will be `abc\0` while the stream is now missing the d: `abcefghij`

Comment: @frklft - Doh! Poor testing on my part, sorry, my test is in the answer. Reading a file of `abcefghij` gives `3 'abc'
7 'abcdefg'` I'll correct my code. I apologise unreservedly.

Comment: @frklft - yes the original has that error also, but a good approach to I/O is to check that the character could be used/stored _before_ reading it, so I should have spotted that. Oh, well :-/

Answer (score 1):

As [Pavan Manjunath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457237/pavan-manjunath) indicates, you have bugs in your program. At least one other one that I can see right away is that you do not handle NUL characters in the file: at the end of the function you use `strlen`, which only measures your sting up to the first NUL byte, which isn't necessarily as many bytes as you actually read.

But that's bugs in general. You asked about error checking specifically. Nobody has mentioned the most important place to check for errors: if there is an error reading the file. You should check the return value of `fgetc()` for EOF as described in its manpage (preferred) or use the `ferror()` function afterwards to test if an error has occurred reading the file.

Checking `peek` and `stream` for NULL as suggested by [Thiruvalluvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/thiruvalluvar) is defensive, but I wouldn't say necessary. Those shouldn't be NULL. If they are, it's your caller's fault, not yours.

Comment: *Every* I/O operation can fail. You should check that *every* I/O function call worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Thiruvalluvar has noted,

1. If the file is an empty one `peek` would just contain a `NULL` character. `i = strlen(peek)` will return `0` but you are still entering the loop as you have `i>=0` and trying to push back a character into the stream which you never got from there. The same case results even when `len` is zero!
2. One more is you are not monitoring the return value of `ungetc`. It might return `EOF` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking the pointers for `NULL` and `if (len > 0)` I'd advise you to check if the `FILE *` is a valid one. You can do it by passing it to `fileno()` and checking if it returns a value different from `-1`.